# Transform a Matrix as an expression

Tags: matrix, products

If I have a matrix that I know it can be written as (xi.xi)*KroneckerProduct(H,xi), where xi and H are vectors. Is there a way to obtain this expression from a given matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can find $H$ as the only right eigenvector that is not in the nullspace, and $\xi$ as the only left eigenvector that is not in the nullspace:

Start with a random setup:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 5;
H = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];
ξ = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n];
M = (ξ.ξ) * KroneckerProduct[H, ξ];
```

Find the right-eigenvector $H_n$ associated with the largest (the only non-zero) eigenvalue:

```
Hn = MaximalBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[M]], Abs@*First][[1, 2]]
(*    {0.144727, 0.0201009, 0.453794, -0.43748, -0.762452}    *)
```

Find the left-eigenvector $\xi_n$ associated with the largest (the only non-zero) eigenvalue:

```
ξn = MaximalBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[Transpose[M]]], Abs@*First][[1, 2]]
(*    {-0.545246, 0.071208, 0.051889, -0.833442, 0.0178092}    *)
```

$H_n$ is proportional to $H$, and $\xi_n$ is proportional to $\xi$:

```
Hn/H
(*    {-0.284707, -0.284707, -0.284707, -0.284707, -0.284707}    *)

ξn/ξ
(*    {0.49814, 0.49814, 0.49814, 0.49814, 0.49814}    *)
```

Scale $\xi_n$ so that the original equation is satisfied:

```
ξξ = ξn * Surd[Tr[M]/Tr[KroneckerProduct[Hn, ξn]], 3];
```

Now $\xi\xi$ and $H_n$ are solutions to your problem:

```
M == (ξξ.ξξ) * KroneckerProduct[Hn, ξξ]
(*    True    *)
```

There are many other ways of scaling these vectors. I've chosen the one where $H_n$ is normalized and $\xi\xi$ is scaled to match; other choices are possible, for example keeping $\xi_n$ normalized and scaling $H_n$ to match:

```
HH = Hn * Tr[M]/Tr[KroneckerProduct[Hn, ξn]];
M == (ξn.ξn) * KroneckerProduct[HH, ξn]
(*    True    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Generate a test matrix `mat`

```
n = 5;

SeedRandom[1234];

HH = RandomReal[10, n];

X = RandomReal[1, n];

mat = (X . X)*KroneckerProduct[HH, X];
```

For a given `mat`, solve for `xi` and `H`

```
xi = Array[x, n];

H = Array[h, n];

sol = NMinimize[
    Total[(Flatten[(xi . xi)*KroneckerProduct[H, xi]] - 
        Flatten[Rationalize[mat, 0]])^2], Flatten[{xi, H}], 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20][[2]] /. v_Real :> N[v]

(*{x[1] -> 2.05585, x[2] -> 1.20557, x[3] -> 1.06273, x[4] -> 0.543965, 
 x[5] -> 1.68477, h[1] -> 0.804353, h[2] -> 0.478941, h[3] -> 0.0791164, 
 h[4] -> 0.346763, h[5] -> 0.0106848} *)
```

Verifying,

```
mat == ((xi . xi)*KroneckerProduct[H, xi] /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Then

```
xi /. sol

(* {2.05585, 1.20557, 1.06273, 0.543965, 1.68477} *)

H /. sol

(* {0.804353, 0.478941, 0.0791164, 0.346763, 0.0106848} *)
```